# How to view ArcGIS layer legend in Android?

Tags: android, arcgis

I have 3 layers (Drainage, Bridge and Slope) in my ArcGIS Feature Server. My Android App view each layer on `ArcGISmap`, and set layer visibility based on checkbox tick. I am using ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android (version 100.1).

My question is, is it possible to **view the layers' legend from feature server into my Layers dialog**? Means to replace the 3 cute icons.

*Android App (Layers dialog in the middle)*

[image]

*Feature Server (layers' legend on left)*

[image]

Thank you in advance!

---

## UPDATE

Thanks to [**falldownhill**'s suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45991073/5245585) to use [Create Swatch](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/symbology/Symbol.html#createSwatchAsync(int,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry))! This is my working code

```
// Loop each layer
for (int x=0; x<featureLayer.length; x++)
{
    try
    {
        // Try get each layer legend
        final ListenableFuture<List<LegendInfo>> layerLegend = featureLayer[x].fetchLegendInfosAsync();

        final int finalX = x;
        layerLegend.addDoneListener(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    // Get each layer legend
                    List<LegendInfo> legendInfo = layerLegend.get();
                    Symbol legendSymbol = legendInfo.get(0).getSymbol();
                    ListenableFuture<Bitmap> symbolSwatch = legendSymbol.createSwatchAsync(MainActivity.this, Color.TRANSPARENT);

                    // Set each layer legend
                    Bitmap symbolBitmap = symbolSwatch.get();
                    ImageView swatchImg = (ImageView) drawerDialog.findViewById(layerImageViewId[finalX]);
                    swatchImg.setImageBitmap(symbolBitmap);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    //showMessage("Animation interrupted");
                }
                catch (ExecutionException e)
                {
                    // Deal with exception during animation...
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Ignore changing layer legend
    }
}
```

*Android App (Updated layers dialog with desired legend in the middle)*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [Create Swatch](https://developers.arcgis.com/android/latest/api-reference/reference/com/esri/arcgisruntime/symbology/Symbol.html#createSwatchAsync(int,%20int,%20float,%20int,%20com.esri.arcgisruntime.geometry.Geometry)) will do what you're looking for.

Just to show one way to use it:

```
float density = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
for (FeatureType type : featureTable.getFeatureTypes()) {
  for (FeatureTemplate template : type.getTemplates()) {
    Geometry geometry = //create whatever shape you want the swatch to be
    Feature feature = featureTable.createFeature(template, geometry);
    Symbol symbol = featureLayer.getRenderer().getSymbol(feature);
    ListenableFuture<Bitmap> symbolSwatch = symbol.createSwatchAsync(24, 24,
        density,color,feature.getGeometry());

    Bitmap swatch = symbolSwatch.get();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried this code and try show the swatch on ImageView like this `ImageView swatchImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.swatchImg); swatchImg.setImageBitmap(swatch);` but no image shown. Can u help me explain the flow in your understanding? Bcs I still didnt understand what the code do.. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thanks, Create Swatch works!  I updated the solution in my question.